# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters in Scala

Tags: strings, array, interview-questions, functional-programming, scala

Question is taken from Leetcode and solution works for their test cases. I do see a scope of improvement and make it more functional (getting rid of vars and mutables data structures). Please suggest improvement to help me.

**Problem**

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

```
Input: "abcabcbb"
Output: 3 

Input: "bbbbb"
Output: 1

Input: "pwwkew"
Output: 3
```

**code**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object Solution extends App{

    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String): Int = {
      if (s.isEmpty) 0
      else {
      val lookupTable = HashMap[Char,Int]()
      var start = 0
      var length = 0
      for ( (c, i) <- s.zipWithIndex) {
        if (!(lookupTable contains c)) {
          lookupTable(c) = i
        } else {
          val newLength = i - start
          if (newLength > length) length = newLength
          start = lookupTable(c) + 1
          lookupTable.retain((k,v) => v >= start)
          lookupTable(c) = i
        }
      }
      Math.max(length, (s.length - start))
    }
  }
    Seq("abcabcbb", "pwwkew", "", "nnnn", "b", "  ", "aab" , "abca" ,"abba") foreach { s =>
      println(s + " = " + lengthOfLongestSubstring(s))
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
abcabcbb = 3
pwwkew = 3
 = 0
nnnn = 1
b = 1
   = 1
aab = 2
abca = 3
abba = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some observations while looking over the code:

1. `if (s.isEmpty) 0` - This isn't necessary. The code produces the correct results without this test. Removing it would reduce the level of indenting for the rest of the code.
2. `if (!(lookupTable contains c))` - [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) suggests that it is usually better to test for the positive condition, especially when there is an `else` block. It's often much easier to read and parse that way. In this case the `else` condition is "NOT table has c == false". (*Ouch!*)
3. `val newLength` - You actually don't need this variable. Try:`length = length max i - start`
4. `lookupTable(c) = i` - This assignment is made on both sides of the `if` test, which means it really doesn't belong there.

   ```
   if (lookupTable contains c) {
     length = length max i - start
     start = lookupTable(c) + 1
     lookupTable.retain((k,v) => v >= start)
   }
   lookupTable(c) = i
   ```

But, of course, the most noteworthy is the use of mutable variables and data structures. Sometimes we have to fall back on imperative programming if functional means/methods are creating a bottleneck, but, short of that, the point of learning/using Scala is its Functional Programming capability.

Here's a reworking of the same algorithm using two index values to access a static array of characters. Each index is advanced via tail-recursive methods so everything remains immutable.

```
def lengthOfMaxSubstring(s: String): Int = {
  val chars: Array[Char] = s.toArray

  def headForward(leadx: Int, rearx: Int, cSet: Set[Char], best: Int): Int = {

    def tailForward(tlx: Int, cs: Set[Char]): (Int, Set[Char]) =
      if (chars(tlx) == chars(leadx)) (tlx + 1, cs)
      else tailForward(tlx + 1, cs - chars(tlx))

    if (leadx >= chars.length) best max leadx-rearx
    else if (cSet(chars(leadx))) {
      val (newTail, newSet) = tailForward(rearx, cSet)
      headForward(leadx+1, newTail, newSet, best max leadx-rearx)
    } else
      headForward(leadx+1, rearx, cSet + chars(leadx), best)
  }
  headForward(0, 0, Set(), 0)
}
```